# Выставить рандомное значение в Mysql

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Как в таблице `dle_post_extras` проставить рандомное число от 500 до 10000 в столбец `rating` в каждую ячейку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Рандомное - своё в каждую запись или одно во все?

Comment: Вместо выделенных нолей, разные числа

Comment: своё в каждую запись

Answer (score 1):

Главная проблема может быть в получении рандомного числа из диапазона, для этого используют такую команду:

```
FLOOR((RAND() * (max-min+1))+min)
```

Оно вернет число из диапазона `min <= x <= max`. Дальше просто последовательно обновляете каждую запись в таблице.